# Will there be an Ethereum Constantinople Fork coin and which exchanges would be supporting it?

Tags: exchanges, forks, constantinople

There are reports of nodes that still haven't upgraded their Ethereum nodes and they are on the Ethereum Constantinople fork. Would a new coin exist and which exchanges have shown support for something like this?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://forkmon.ethdevops.io/, 7 blocks have been mined on the ConstantiNOple chain, while 2696 have been mined (at the time of writing) on the non-ConstantiNOple chain. That means ~14 ConstantiNOple eth have been mined while 8088 non-ConstantiNOple eth has been mined. It's highly unlikely that any support will come from this, seeing as the hashrate was obviously so small and there likely is no hashrate on it anymore